# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS KVM host with a OpenBSD 5.4 guest, `virsh shutdown` not working / freezing guest

Tags: ubuntu, kvm-virtualization, ubuntu-12.04, openbsd

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS KVM host with a OpenBSD 5.4 guest.

**I am having an issue with `virsh shutdown` not working / freezing guest.**

After calling shutdown, guest freezes and is unresponsive.  Any ssh sessions freeze, and any vnc consoles are unresponsive.  Nothing in the client logs at time of freeze.

Only resolution is to destroy guest in vish.

---

The issue appears similar to:
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.os.openbsd.misc/200982

---

### Shutdown From Host

- From host:

`$ sudo virsh list --all
...
 15 ssh2                 running
...`

`$ sudo virsh shutdown ssh2
Domain ssh2 is being shutdown`

`$ sudo virsh list --all
...
 15 ssh2                 running
...`

- After waiting 5 min, no status change.

### Shutdown From Guest

- Wathcing log during hist shutdown request:

`sudo tail -F /var/log/messages`

- No additional values logged as result of shutodwn request.
- Terminal (ssh) and console (via vnc) both become unresponsive.
- Terminal (ssh) eventaully errors with `Write failed: Broken pipe`.

### Host Details

- Host:

`$ uname -a
Linux kvm2 3.2.0-51-generic #77-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 24 20:18:19 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS"`

- Host kvm version:

`$ virsh version
Compiled against library: libvir 0.9.8
Using library: libvir 0.9.8
Using API: QEMU 0.9.8
Running hypervisor: QEMU 1.0.0`

- Host kvm dominfo on guest:

`$ virsh dominfo ssh2
Id:             -
Name:           ssh2
UUID:           7bb1977e-7268-f40a-32d4-5ae972be7e5f
OS Type:        hvm
State:          shut off
CPU(s):         2
Max memory:     524288 kB
Used memory:    524288 kB
Persistent:     yes
Autostart:      disable
Managed save:   no
Security model: apparmor
Security DOI:   0`

### Guest Install Steps

- Downloaded amd64 install54.iso:
  http://ftp.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/5.4/amd64/install54.iso
- Create disk:

`sudo qemu-img create -f qcow2 -o preallocation=metadata /vm/ssh2-disk0.qcow2 2G`

- Run virt-install:

`sudo virt-install \
--name ssh2 \
--ram 512 \
--vcpus=1 \
--os-variant=openbsd4 \
--hvm \
--cdrom /vm/install/install54-amd64.iso \
--network bridge:br0,model=virtio \
--graphics vnc \
--disk path=/vm/ssh2-disk0.qcow2,bus=virtio,size=2`

- Note: Used br0 instead of virbr0, as host uses br0.
- From kvm:

`sudo virsh vncdisplay ssh2`

- From desktop:

`ssh -L 5910:127.0.0.1:5909 kvm2`

- Connect over vnc to localhost 5910, continue install.
- Did not install game54.tgz or any x packages:

`-game*
-x*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qemu makes assumptions about ACPI that OpenBSD does not. Over the course of multiple OpenBSD and multiple Qemu/KVM versions, I have found the only way to effectively shut an OpenBSD guest down is with

```
halt -p
```

in the guest itself.

Comment: This was the conclusion I was arriving at too.  

I was looking at the 'echo system_powerdown' to the monitor to see if that worked as expected.

Comment: There are no assumptions. QEMU simply sends an ACPI shutdown request to the guest. If the guest cannot honour such a request, the command will not work.

Comment: No, I remember seeing this on openbsd-tech@; it has to do with overwriting ECX (IIRC) when the OpenBSD context is returning. (And now that I say that it it's probably KVM that's making that assumption, given that...)

Comment: @Bandrami Only subscribers can read OpenBSD mailing list archives. Can you find this information and summarize it for interested parties?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem with OpenBSD as a vm when trying to shutdown in KVM.

Solved by:

```
root@myhost:~# config -ef /bsd
disable mpbios
q
root@myhost:~# reboot
```

Comment: Thanks, but this was one of the first things I tried.